# Publish NServiceBus events from command handler

Tags: nservicebus, publish-subscribe, nservicebus4

I'm trying to implement a simple POC for a NServiceBus solution.
So I implemented 3 endpoints, let's call them A,B and C.
A is self hosted in a console app, B and C are NSB hosts.
In A I'm sending a command DoFoo, in B I'm handling DoFoo and inside the handler I publish several events of type BarOccurred like so:

```
for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
{
  Bus.Publish(new BarOccurred);
  Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

In C I'm subscribing and handling it by writing to the console that Bar occurred.

I expected to see the message handled in C every time that B publishes it (i.e every second). However the behavior I see is that only after the command handler exit (after 5 iterations) only then all 5 messages are received by C.

Is that the expected behavior for the default configuration? Is there anything I need to declare in order to have messages sent and processed as soon as they are published?

Answer (score 0):

The Bus.Publish is in a single transaction and commits once all messages have been sent.  I would see if packaging all the messages in one Bus.Publish(IMesssage[]) may meet your needs.  This turns into 1 message on the wire.

Comment: I think it might be better to say that the message processing is (by default) a single transaction - including all publishes, meaning that nothing is published until the handler completes.

Comment: Thanks Adam and @UdiDahan. How would one change the default configuration to support my scenario? In my system, I have a command that is triggered from the UI and starts a process of scanning. I want that each time a frame is acquired, some image processing algorithm would process that frame. I want the processing and scanning to run concurrently. What is the configuration/implementation that I should use?

Comment: In this case, it could be that disabling transactions would be the way to go.

Comment: @UdiDahan thanks again! Can one disable transactions for a specific message type? for a single endpoint? all commands? If someone would put it in an answer form with some code and explanations that'd be great.

Comment: Disabling transactions can be done per endpoint only right now.

Comment: @UdiDahan I would accept your suggestion to disable transactions for the endpoint as an answer, but I can't vote for the current answer.

Comment: `TransactionScope` is thread-safe so it may be an option to leave the endpoint transactional and implement a worker thread for the scanning / publishing.